# Removing Empty Accounts in Balanced Payments

Tags: php, rest, balanced-payments

I am using the Balanced Payments PHP API to work in one of our Test Marketplaces. My concern about creating & removing Marketplaces was already answered by another StackOverflow topic (removed after 90 days of inactivity) but I was wondering if empty Accounts have the same behavior?

In testing, I've already created a number of empty Accounts with no Bank/CC information and no transactions attached. I would like to be able to delete these to reduce the clutter on the Balanced dashboard, but they don't seem to be deletable.

Do these accounts automatically delete themselves or is there some other way to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t currently delete accounts, but you can make as many new test marketplaces as you want, if you’re worried about clutter.

There’s some discussion about allowing deletion of various resources at https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/issues/29

Comment: Perfect, that link helped explain things exactly. I wasn't too worried about the Test Marketplace clutter, more about if an Account ended up getting orphaned in a Production Marketplace. It looks like enabling deletions are still being discussed.